# How to search and replace for multiple words in one shot

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, sed, scripting

I need to search and replace multiple words. For example, in my file, I want to search for any name of week days that appears with a comma after it: `Sat,` or `Sun,` or `Mon,` or `Tue,` or `Wed,` or `Thur,` or `Fri,` to a name without comma: `Saturday` or `Sunday` or `Monday` or `Tuesday` or `Wednesday` or `Thursday` or `Friday`. I know how to do this one by one:

```
sed 's/Sat,/Saturday/g' myfile.txt > output.txt
```

But due to the fact that I have to check every week day in multiple files, I need to find a more efficient way to check all the names and replace them at once. I am aware this can be done through scripting but I have not worked on that before. If someone familiar with this, I can learn from it this time and do it myself next time.

Comment: Take a look at GNU sed's option `-f` and `-i`. See: `man sed`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can chain multiple `sed` expressions with `-e` like this:

```
sed -e 's/Sat,/Saturday/g' -e 's/Sun,/Sunday/g' <file>
```

This will replace all occurrences of `Sat,` with `Saturday` and all occurrences of `Sun,` with `Sunday`.

Comment: Why do you add `-e` ??

Comment: `-e` means script or `--expression` otherwise  `sed` will interpret the second argument as the first `<file>` to use and it will error with .. *can't read s/Sun/Sunday/g: No such file or directory*

Comment: How to ignore case-sensitivity in sed? because the day name may or may not be capital letter.

Comment: use `/ig` or `/Ig`at the end of the expression

Comment: Shouldn't the search text (`Sat`, `Sun`, here) have commas after them?

Answer (score 0):

Thought I'd share this solution.  The media subtitles that I download are filled with NSFC (Not Safe For Children) words. This removes objectionable words recursively:

`find . -type f -name "*.srt" -exec sed -i 's/\(word1\|word2\|word3\|word4\|word5\|word6\|word7\|word8\)//g' {} +`

This verifies their removal:

`grep --include=\*.srt -rnwE . -e 'word1|word2|word3|word4|word5|word6|word7|word8'`